# Transformar 2 array php em um unico array

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp

Tenho 2 `Arrays`:

```
"val" => {
    "0": "2"
    "1": "4"
    "2": "6"
    "3": null
    "4": null
}

"p" => {
    "0": "4"
    "1": "5"
    "2": "7"
    "3": "8"
    "4": "9"
}
```

Diante disso quero pegar os elementos do `array` `val` que são 2 4 6 e adicionar no mesmo 4 5 7.

Tudo em um único `array`.

Comment: `array_merge()`?

Comment: Coloque o resultado esperado na pergunta também, assim como sua tentativa de solução descrevendo o erro que encontrou.

Answer (score 3):

Boa tarde, vamos começar: primeiramente você pode utilizar o [Array_merge](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php) para juntar os 2 arrays, pegando pelo exemplo que você deu você tem os 2 arrays:

```
$val = [
    "0" => "2",
    "1" => "4",
    "2" => "6",
    "3" => null,
    "4" => null
];

$p = [
    "0" => "4",
    "1" => "5",
    "2" => "7",
    "3" => "8",
    "4" => "9"
];
```

Exemplo:

```
$array_mergido = array_merge($val, $p);
```

Porém caso você queira somente valores únicos sem serem repetidos você poderá utilzar o [Array_unique](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php):

```
$array_mergido = array_unique(array_merge($val, $p));
```

Comment: o princípio é o mesmo, `$val = array('banana', 'maçã');

$p = array('batata', 'cenoura');

$array_mergido = array_merge($val, $p);`